# SQL query not finding correct answer

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to figure out website visits. Every visit within 30 minutes should count as one visit for that user.

My table looks like this

```
TimeUser,             Userid,    OrderID

10/7/2013 14:37:14  _26Tf-0PjaS0dpiZXB61Rg  151078706
10/7/2013 14:39:59  _26Tf-0PjaS0dpiZXB61Rg  151078706
10/7/2013 14:40:35  _26Tf-0PjaS0dpiZXB61Rg  151078706
10/11/2013 0:09:23  _2MrGz4L_d5AF3UHpP-oJQ  151078706
10/2/2013 20:55:05  _4Pb2wEwiQomUny_XwVuvQ  151078706
10/2/2013 20:55:06  _4Pb2wEwiQomUny_XwVuvQ  151078706
10/2/2013 20:55:06  _4Pb2wEwiQomUny_XwVuvQ  151078706
```

In this case 151078706  should return 3 visits.
I think my SQL query looks right, but when I check my answer with my Excel created Visits number, some of orders off by 5%. I am hundred percent sure Excel numbers are correct.

Here is what I have so far. If anyone sees any issue with my query please correct me. And also if there any other better ways to find visits?

```
SET @row_num=0,
    @temp_row=1;


SELECT orderidtable.orders,
       count(orderidtable.users)
FROM
  (SELECT temptab.temprow,
          temptab.userid users,
          temptab.orderid orders,
          temptab.TimeUser
   FROM
     (SELECT @row_num := @row_num + 1 AS rownumber, TimeUser,
                                                    userid,
                                                    orderid
      FROM order.order_dec
      ORDER BY orderid,
               userid,
               timeuser) subtable ,
     (SELECT @temp_row:= @temp_row+1 AS temprow, Timeuser,
                                                 userid,
                                                 orderid
      FROM
      ORDER.order_dec
      ORDER BY orderid,
               userid,
               timeuser) temptab
   WHERE (subtable.rownumber=temptab.temprow
          AND abs(Time_To_Sec(subtable.TimeUser)-Time_To_Sec(temptab.TimeUser))>=1800)
     OR (subtable.rownumber=temptab.temprow
         AND subtable.userid<>temptab.userid)
     OR (subtable.rownumber=temptab.temprow
         AND subtable.orderid<>temptab.orderid)) orderidtable
GROUP BY orderidtable.orders
```

Comment: Ugh, you'll want to remove all those HTML tags from your post.  Then you can select your query and click the code button ({})

Comment: Since when did September get 31 days? :D

Answer (score 1):

Numbering the rows is a right strategy; your query is going wrong in `where` condition.

Algorithm to solve it would be:

1. Number the rows ordering by `orderid, userid, timeuser`. Make two copies (subtable and temptable) of this dataset as you are already doing.
2. Join these tables on following condition:

   ```
   subtable.rownumber =temptab.temprow + 1
   ```

   What we trying to do here is to join the tables in a manner such that a row of `subtable` joins with a row of `temptable` with rownumber 1 lesser than its own. We are doing it to be capable of comparing consecutive time of visits of an user to an Ad. (You have already done it by setting @row_num=0, @temp_row=1). This is the only condition we should apply to the JOIN.
3. Now in the `SELECT` statement use `CASE` statement like below

   `(CASE WHEN subtable.orderid = temptable.orderid AND subtable.userid = temptable.userid AND (Time_To_Sec(subtable.TimeUser)-Time_To_Sec(temptab.TimeUser))< 1800 THEN 0
         ELSE 1) As IsVisit`
4. Now in an outer query GROUP BY `order_id` and in `SELECT` sum up IsVisit.

Let me know should you need more clarity or let me know if it worked.

Addendum:
From the previous query you can try replacing the `where` condition as subtable.rownumber = temptab.temprow + 4 and in SELECT statement replace the `CASE` statement of above query with the following:

```
 (CASE WHEN subtable.orderid = temptable.orderid AND subtable.userid = temptable.userid AND (Time_To_Sec(subtable.TimeUser)-Time_To_Sec(temptab.TimeUser))< 900 THEN 1
      ELSE 0) As IsVisit
```

Take `UNION` of the result set returned by previous query and this one, and then apply `GROUP BY`.

Comment: I just tested, i got exactly same answer. I added ABS() in time calculation formula. I guess excel calculated number is incorrect.I used same approach for my excel calculation, but i am not sure why answers are different.  Thanks for the  help.

Comment: Take a subset of dataset and try comparing the results, that might give you a clue.

Comment: oh, i think query is correct. Excel was not calculating visit based on previous row, it was based on first time that user visited. would it be hard to calculate if 4 visits within 15 minutes of gap considered as 2 visits?

Comment: Check the Addendum above

Comment: What i meant was for example if user visits at 15:00:00, 15:01:01 15:05:00... so on 15:29:01, 15:31:01, 15:41:00,15:51:00. This should count as two visits, Because at 15:00:00 user see as an ad first time, then timer is at 0 then at 15:31:01 should be the second visit, because this visit is after 1800 sec since last visit, Then timer should reinitialize at 0 Sec. 15:41:00 and 15:51:00 should not be third because since second visit, 1800 seconds was not passed.

Answer (score 0):

One issue I see: Your query is overly complex.
What about this?

Now then, both your original and this query will err when there's a visit near midnight, and another visit right shortly after it - in this case, both queries will count them as 2 visits when they really should be counted as one, if I understood your request correctly. From this simplified query, though, it should be easy for you to do the required change.

```
SELECT orderidtable.OrderID, COUNT(orderidtable.UserID) visits
FROM (
    SELECT Timeuser, Userid, OrderID
      FROM order.order_dec SubTab1
     WHERE NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT 1 FROM order.order_dec SubTab2
             WHERE SubTab1.OrderID  = SubTab2.OrderID
               AND SubTab2.TimeUser > SubTab2.TimeUser
               AND Time_To_Sec(SubTab2.TimeUser)
                   BETWEEN Time_To_Sec(SubTab1.OrderID)
                       AND Time_To_Sec(SubTab1.OrderID)+1800
    )
) orderidtable
GROUP BY orderidtable.OrderID
```

Comment: thank you, this query looks simpler, but my table has about 1million rows and many different orderids and userids. So i think query will run very slow. my original query run about 180 sec

Comment: @eric.g But, have you actually *tried it*??? There are several problems with your original query: it (ab)uses inner queries, it does the exact same sub-query twice and then joins them via a complex condition. And it depends on auto-numbering the rows! All that's surely going to make your query go VERY slow, no matter how many indexes you have. I think this query should be a bit faster while also simpler to fix/modify when the need arises.

Comment: i tested it. i stopped the query after about hour. I originally had similar query to yours, but it was running very slow, So i added row numbers.

Comment: Ah, now that sounds like a challenge! I'm really interested in improving your times. Could you please provide the DDL of your table in the original question, as well as any indexes that might exist, please? Also, could you please provide some more sample rows and what should and should not be returned?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I updated the table, It is website log for user, and orderID(It is ad ID). There are nothing else in original table, just time, userid, and orderid. My goal is to find how many unique visits per orderid. If users see same ad within 30 minutes since they last saw that ad, that visit is not unique visits. It is only unique if visit is after 30 minuts since user last saw that same ad. I am okay with performance of query, but for some reason i am getting incorrect visits.

Comment: @eric.g, if a user makes 4 visits in an hour at a gap of 15 minutes between two consecutive visits, would be counted a single visit or two visits?

Comment: it should count as a single visit. @DipenduPaul

Answer (score 0):

I think just one time table full scan is sufficient for what you want as follows.

You can test here. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a5dbcd/1.

Although my Query is not tested on many sample data, I think minor change is needed if it has bugs.

```
SELECT MAX(current_uv) AS uv
FROM (
  SELECT orderid, userid, timeuser,
    IF(orderid != @prev_orderid, @prev_timeuser := 0, @prev_timeuser) AS prev_timeuser,
    @prev_orderid := orderid AS prev_orderid,

    IF(userid != @prev_userid, @prev_timeuser := 0, @prev_timeuser) AS prev_timeuser2,
    @prev_userid := userid AS prev_userid,

    IF(TO_SECONDS(timeuser) - @prev_timeuser > 1800, @current_uv := @current_uv + 1, @current_uv) AS current_uv,
    @prev_timeuser := TO_SECONDS(timeuser) AS prev_timeuser3
  FROM order_dec,
    (SELECT @prev_orderid := 0, @prev_userid = '', @prev_timeuser := 0, @current_uv := 0) init
  ORDER BY orderid, userid, timeuser
) x;
```